# maximum out put swing question - Transistor

Tags: transistors, mosfet

For example, given two mosfets that have different Vd,sat, but their vout is situated at half the supply range, would it be possible for both transistors to have a maximum output swing? My thinking is that they cant since they have different Vd,sat, making the their output swing some "headroom" if one is maximized. However, I am confused because from what i understand, usually, a transistor's output swing is maximized if there its Vout is half the supply range. Any insight is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you are asking.

I think one can design it somehow.

I think nobody is ever interested because it's not a real need for electronics and yet it might cost much more in terms of part count that using a single MOSFET.

Comment: so the output voltage should always be half of the supply range so that it will have a maximum output swing?

Comment: We design single transistor amplifiers in order to maximize the output voltage swing. Many times, but not always, the output voltage when there's no input signal applied is at VDD/2, that is half of the supply.